# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts for VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that there are many questions and answers regarding having VisualStudio keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse.

I'm actually interested in the opposite: having Eclipse keyboard shortcuts in VisualStudio.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any direct Eclipse shortcuts or key-bindings to import directly in Visual Studio. (only [official supported languages are documented](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f))

That leaves only a manual settings, I am afraid.